# 8-digit sequences invoving exactly 6 different digits

Tags: combinatorics

How many 8-digit sequences are there involving exactly six different digits? How can I approach this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

HINT:

- Count the ways to choose a set of $6$ digits to use.
- Given a set of $6$ digits, either you use one digit $3$ times, or you use two digits twice each. Treat those cases separately.
- In each case you must first choose the digit(s) to be duplicated; in how many ways can that be done? Then you’re solving a problem of the same general type as counting the number of distinguishable arrangements of the letters in the name MISSISSIPPI; I expect that you’ve done some problems of that type.
- Properly combine the results of the previous steps.

Comment: Thanks, I probably should have looked at it more closely. I completely missed the case where you could have two digits twice. Thanks.

Comment: @gandolf: You’re welcome.

Comment: I believe it has been some time since this question has been asked but can someone confirm if the following is the answer?
$$
\binom{10}{6}\binom{6}{1}\frac{8!}{3!} + \binom{10}{6}\binom{6}{2}\frac{8!}{2!2!}
$$
PS: Tagging @BrianM.Scott

Comment: @Kom: Looks good!